# Python in Jupyter Notebook: .append kept adding without refresh the list in each run

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, append

Please help with `append()` in a loop that behaves weird as shown below.

I have a string.

1. I extract alphabet letters from the string and store to a list, called `ltr`.
2. I specify the conditions for each element of the `ltr` list
3. I stored the boolean result in a list, called `ltr_spec`
4. It looks fine for the first run if I purposely run `ltr_spec = []` in another cell of Jupyter Notebook to initialize `ltr_spec`.
5. However, if I run the cell again, `ltr_spec` keep adding new elements without being refreshed as an empty list which was define at the beginning of the code.
6. Note that the first `append()` in `ltr.append()` behaves as expected. But the second `append()` in `ltr_spec.append()` behaves unexpected when run the cell in Jupyter Notebook.

Would you please kindly tell me if it is the issue of the loop, or `append()`, or Jupyter Notebook?

Sample code below.

```
s ='Qm1p4Q7p5d2'
ltr = []
# Test if each element of 'ltr' satisfies the spec of alphabet letter in a string
ltr_j = False
ltr_spc = []

for i in s:
    if i.isalpha():
        ltr.append(i)
# Utilize the modulo operation, a math concept, to locate the position of the letters
if (len(ltr) % 3 == 0):
    for j in range(len(ltr)):
        # Test ltr list on the specs of index, letter, and upper/lower case
        if ((j % 3 == 0 and ltr[j] == "Q") or
                # Ask if there is a better way to write j %in% c(1,2) (R's match function) without using Numpy!
            (j % 3 == 1 and ((ltr[j] == "d" and ltr[j+1] == "p") or (ltr[j] == "p" and ltr[j+1] == "d"))) or
                # Ask if the following condition is redundant given the condition specified above is already checked..
            (j % 3 == 2 and ((ltr[j] == "d" and ltr[j-1] == "p") or (ltr[j] == "p" and ltr[j-1] == "d")))):
                ltr_j = True
        else:
            ltr_j = False
        ltr_spec.append(ltr_j)
```

Output in first run:

```
ltr
['Q', 'm', 'p', 'Q', 'p', 'd']
ltr_spec
[True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Output in second run:

```
ltr
['Q', 'm', 'p', 'Q', 'p', 'd']
ltr_spec
[True, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True, True]
```

Output in third run:

```
ltr
['Q', 'm', 'p', 'Q', 'p', 'd']
ltr_spec
[True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 True,
 True]
```

Comment: There's a typo: you define `ltr_spc` in the cell but append to `ltr_spec` which you probably defined elsewhere, so it keeps appending to that list instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @fsimonjetz Thank you so much! I was wondering why it worked before lunch but not after lunch. I added the initialization of  `ltr_spc = []` after lunch .

Comment: @fsimonjetz After corrected the typo, more strange thing happened. Now the length of `ltr_spec` is not the same length as `ltr` anymore. ``` ltr ['Q', 'm', 'p', 'Q', 'p', 'd']

ltr_spec [False, False, True, True]```

Comment: Sometimes you need to restart kernel and clear output. Or it would be better if all lines of code is in the same cell to assure that you do not, by accident, initialize the variables in other cell that you do not re-run as suggested by @fsimonjetz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `ltr_spc = []` but at the bottom you call `ltr_spec.append(ltr_j)`, so the list is not emptied.

[Here](https://onecompiler.com/python/3yybazc9x) is the code after correct `ltr_spc = []` to `ltr_spec = []`, and it gives consistent output after re-run many times.

Comment: thanks! I shutdown the kernel and restart it. It works as you showed.